# first child css is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```html
<div class="parent-div">
 
 <p>
  <b>1. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>2. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>3. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

 <p>
  <b>4. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>5. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>6. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

</div>
```

I want to hide the 1st most `<b>` tag and wrote :

```
.parent-div b:first-child {display:none;}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that with `.parent-div b:first-child {display:none;}` you are hidding the first b tag of every `<p>` element. To only hide the first `<b>` in the first `<p>` you can use `.parent-div p:first-child b:first-child {display:none;}` :

```css
.parent-div p:first-child b:first-child {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
 
 <p>
  <b>1. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>2. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>3. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

 <p>
  <b>4. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>5. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>6. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent-div > p b:first-child {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
 
 <p>
  <b>1. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>2. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>3. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

 <p>
  <b>4. Some dummy text</b><br>
  <b>5. Some other dummy text</b><br>
  <b>6. Some other more dummy text</b><br>
 </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change css

```
.parent-div p b:first-child {display:none;}
```